# Glob glob does not read file and nothing is working after I run code

Tags: python, image, file, opencv, glob

I am a newbie in Python .

I`ve tried to run this code for image processing for multiple images but nothing seems to work.

No error comes out and the console mentioned that it has run file.

When I exclude glob and try to run for one file the system seems to work just fine.
Can anyone advise me on this.

I have try to reset spyder, reload anaconda and it seems like nothing change

The code are as follow.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
import math
import glob

path = 'C:/users/OneDrive/Bubble visualization/4mm/L7.5G122/*.bmp'

image_bac = cv2.imread('background_C001H001S0002000001.bmp')

x=0
for file in glob.glob(path):
    x=x+1
    print(x)
    print(file)
    image_bub = cv2.imread(file)
    
    
    # parameters you need to set
    kernelsize = 5#Needs to be a odd number
    threshold = 7#Threshold of binarization
    max_area = 100000#The maximum area of contour [pixel x pixel]
    min_area = 4#The minimum area of contour [pixel x pixel]
    
    # convert color image to gray scale
    img_bub = cv2.cvtColor(image_bub, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    img_bac = cv2.cvtColor(image_bac, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    # convert uint8 image to float32
    img_bub=img_bub.astype(np.float32)
    img_bac=img_bac.astype(np.float32)
    
    # apply background subtraction and replace <0 values by 0
    img_sub=img_bac-img_bub
    img_sub=np.where(img_sub<0,0,img_sub)
    # convert float32 array to uint8 image
    img_sub=img_sub.astype(np.uint8)
    
    cv2.imwrite('img_aftersub.png', img_sub)
    
    
    # apply median filter to denoise and binarize
    img_med = cv2.medianBlur(img_sub,kernelsize)
    ret,img_thresh = cv2.threshold(img_med,threshold,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
    # obtain contour
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    # save only valid contours and its area (in this case identified by size)
    saved_contour = []
    contour_area = []
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if (area < max_area) & (area>min_area):
            saved_contour.append(cnt)
            contour_area.append(area)
    
    # write only valid contours
    img_cnt = cv2.drawContours(image_bub, saved_contour, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
    #saveimage
    cv2.imwrite('img_out.png', img_cnt)
    # show image
    cv2.imshow("output", img_cnt)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# convert list of areas into ndarray
    contour_area1 = np.array(contour_area)

    #convert contour area to area in mm
    area1 = contour_area1**0.0096
    #1mm = 0.0096 pixel
    
    diameter = np.sqrt((4.0*area1)/np.pi)
    
    # calulate the mean and std of area and print
    mean = np.average(diameter)
    std = np.std(diameter)
    print("the average d is: " + str(mean))
    print("the std of d is: " + str(std))
```

I hope some one could point out my mistake in the coding.

Comment: What is the exact issue? "Nothing seems to work" is unclear. Is it expected to overwrite the output (`cv2.imwrite('img_out.png', img_cnt)`)? You should probably make you output name dynamic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the problem is nothing is happenign when i run this coding. The console stated run file...but there are nothing happening. No image or file created, no area was read too. So I was confused on what is the problem actually